# Vue format array to be sent as WA message

Tags: vue.js

I am developing a feature in my app to send messages via Whatsapp.

But I am not sure how to display them. For example given this array:

```
 purchaseOrderMessage() {
      var po = this.currentPurchaseOrder.purchase_order_lines.map(x => {
        return {
          name: x.item_name,
          quantity: x.quantity,
        };
      });
      return po

    },
```

I send the Wa message doing:

```
sendWa() {
      let url = 'https://wa.me/' + this.currentPurchaseOrder.supplier.phone + '?text=' + this.purchaseOrderMessage
      openURL(url)
},
```

How should I format the array to make it readable in the message?

Comment: On a side note: the wa.me API has a limit on the length of text. We've attempted to use WhatsApp integration this way at my workplace before, but had to abandon it due to message length restrictions. I work for an e-commerce company, and sometimes a customer may order a lot of items: the message will end up truncated and practically be useless.

Comment: Thanks I was not aware of that

Comment: But back to your question: since it is formatted as a plain text, there, you will probably want to construct your own way of representing the list. Like, you will need to manually inject line breaks, add bullet characters, and etc.

Comment: Yes the thing is that I don't know how to do it outside the template..

Comment: You basically need to convert the array into a string representation. If you append the array directly, you will invoke the `Array.prototype.toString()` method, which doesn't prettify the list. How you want to prettify the list is up to you: not something that I have an answer for. You can, for example, do `.join('\n')`. Remember to escape your payload using `encodeURIComponent`